# Adding Custom Data Set - get multiple Data Sets on Summary Display page

Tags: custom-fields

I just added a new custom data set (Monitoring Change) inline so it appears on the summary page of our database for each of our customer's details. However, I also moved some old fields from another data set into this new set. Now the summary page is diplaying a whole Monitoring Change data set for each completed field (the old data fields moved to it), in the summary page.

I can't figure out how to change this so there is only one Monitoring Change data set per customer details on the summary page, with both old and new fields together?

Please help!

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  I'm afraid I'm not clear what you mean.  Could you provide some more detail and/or a screenshot (without any confidential data).

Comment: This sounds like your Group of Fields was set up for Multiple Records (though I thought they should only be shown as Tabs but that might be out of data info.

Comment: a screenshot might explain what you have more quickly

Comment: Hi there thanks for gettign back. Yes I think the problem is 'Does this Custom Field Set Allow Multiple Records' inthe settings of the specific data set. This checked with an [x]. I don't know how to uncheck it again and I think this might be the source of the problem? Does anyoen knwo how to uncheck it once the data set is created?

Comment: You can't revert this setting. The storage principles differ too much. I think it's best to create a new set of custom data that fits your needs. After configuring use the api to migrate your data.

Comment: Ok, thank you for letting me know; I had a feeling that might be the case.